# CSS columns vertical overflow workaround

Tags: html, css, scroll, css-multicolumn-layout

I'm trying to arrange images in column-like way using CSS columns within a relatively fixed div. I want the div to scroll vertically but when it reaches the maximum vertical space available it creates new columns at the right forcing the div to scroll horizontally instead of maintaining the 3 intended columns and overflowing vertically. any idea on how to fix it?

```css
    body {
      background-color: white;
      width:100%;
      height:100%;
      position:absolute;
      font-family: "ff-tisa-web-pro",serif;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-weight: 400;
      line-height: 1.45;
      color: #333;
      background: rgba(200,125,06,0.5)
    }

    .grid {
      position:relative;
      height:80%;
      -webkit-columns: 150px;
      -moz-columns: 3 150px;
      columns: 3 150px;
      width:40%;
      margin:auto;
      overflow: auto;
      background: rgba(200,125,06,0.5);
      break-inside: avoid;
    }
  .grid img{
    width:100%;
  }
```

```html
    <div class="grid">
      <img src="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/03434/guinness-eyeballs_3434500k.jpg"/>
      <img src="https://www.allindiaroundup.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/mr-bean-pics-as-a-baby-whatsapp-dp-1024x768.jpg"/>
      <img src="http://www.likecool.com/Gear/Pic/10%20Vintage%20Pics%20Of%20Carrie%20Fisher%20Promoting%20%20Return%20Of%20The%20Jedi%20%20In/10-Vintage-Pics-Of-Carrie-Fisher-Promoting--Return-Of-The-Jedi--In-2.jpg"/>
      <img src="http://8.mshcdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/steve-jobs-finger.jpg"/>
      <img src="https://www.funnypica.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/funny-picture-of-ugly-indian.jpg"/>
      <img src="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/03434/guinness-eyeballs_3434500k.jpg"/>
      <img src="https://www.allindiaroundup.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/mr-bean-pics-as-a-baby-whatsapp-dp-1024x768.jpg"/>
      <img src="http://www.likecool.com/Gear/Pic/10%20Vintage%20Pics%20Of%20Carrie%20Fisher%20Promoting%20%20Return%20Of%20The%20Jedi%20%20In/10-Vintage-Pics-Of-Carrie-Fisher-Promoting--Return-Of-The-Jedi--In-2.jpg"/>
      <img src="http://8.mshcdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/steve-jobs-finger.jpg"/>
      <img src="https://www.funnypica.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/funny-picture-of-ugly-indian.jpg"/>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I had this exact problem, and the solution is to use overflow-y:scroll (or auto) on a parent element and not on the element with a column-count, as the two seem to be incompatible.

Answer (score 1):

Try with 1 column-count and as text get bigger than available height it will auto split in to second column - `columns: 1 150px;`

```css
body {
    background-color: white;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    font-family: "ff-tisa-web-pro",serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.45;
    color: #333;
    padding: 1em;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: rgba(200,125,06,0.5)
  }

  article {
    position:relative;
    height:70%;
    -webkit-columns: 150px;
    -moz-columns: 1 150px;
    columns: 1 150px;
    padding:1em;
    width:40%;
    margin:auto;
    overflow: scroll;
    background: rgba(200,125,06,0.5)
  }
```

```html
<article>
    At noon they sat down by the roadside, near a little brook, and Dorothy opened her basket and got out some bread.  She offered a piece to the Scarecrow, but he refused.
    I am never hungry,&rdquo; he said, &ldquo;and it is a lucky thing I am not, for my mouth is only painted, and if I should cut a hole in it so I could eat, the straw I am stuffed with would come out, and that would spoil the shape of my head.&rdquo;
  Dorothy saw at once that this was true, so she only nodded and went on eating her bread.
  &ldquo;Tell me something about yourself and the country you came from,&rdquo; said the Scarecrow, when she had finished her dinner.  So she told him all about Kansas, and how gray everything was there, and how the cyclone had carried her to this queer Land of Oz.
   &ldquo;Tell me something about yourself and the country you came from,&rdquo; said the Scarecrow, when she had finished her dinner.  So she told him all about Kansas, and how gray everything was there, and how the cyclone had carried her to this queer Land of Oz.
   &ldquo;Tell me something about yourself and the country you came from,&rdquo; said the Scarecrow, when she had finished her dinner.  So she told him all about Kansas, and how gray everything was there, and how the cyclone had carried her to this queer Land of Oz.
    &ldquo;Tell me something about yourself and the country you came from,&rdquo; said the Scarecrow, when she had finished her dinner.  So she told him all about Kansas, and how gray everything was there, and how the cyclone had carried her to this queer Land of Oz.
   &ldquo;Tell me something about yourself and the country you came from,&rdquo; said the Scarecrow, when she had finished her dinner.  So she told him all about Kansas, and how gray everything was there, and how the cyclone had carried her to this queer Land of Oz.
   &ldquo;Tell me something about yourself and the country you came from,&rdquo; said the Scarecrow, when she had finished her dinner.  So she told him all about Kansas, and how gray everything was there, and how the cyclone had carried her to this queer Land of Oz.
  </article>
```

Comment: well the thing is it keeps scrolling horizontally but i want it to scroll vertically

Comment: Actually as `article` height which is 70% of user screen reaches it will start adding remaining text into new column.

Comment: Sorry, I think you're right let me update the snippet so you can see what I mean

Answer (score 1):

Lets see if this helps you.

```css
body {
      background-color: white;      
      height:100%;
      position:absolute;
      font-family: "ff-tisa-web-pro",serif;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-weight: 400;
      line-height: 1.45;
      color: #333;
      background: rgba(200,125,06,0.5)
    }

    .grid {
      position:relative;     
      -webkit-columns:3 150px;
      -moz-columns: 3 150px;
      columns: 3 150px;      
      margin:auto;
      overflow: auto;
      background: rgba(200,125,06,0.5);
      break-inside: avoid;
    }
  .grid img{
    width:100%;
  }
```

```html
<div class="grid">
      <img src="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/03434/guinness-eyeballs_3434500k.jpg"/>
      <img src="https://www.allindiaroundup.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/mr-bean-pics-as-a-baby-whatsapp-dp-1024x768.jpg"/>
      <img src="http://www.likecool.com/Gear/Pic/10%20Vintage%20Pics%20Of%20Carrie%20Fisher%20Promoting%20%20Return%20Of%20The%20Jedi%20%20In/10-Vintage-Pics-Of-Carrie-Fisher-Promoting--Return-Of-The-Jedi--In-2.jpg"/>
      <img src="http://8.mshcdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/steve-jobs-finger.jpg"/>
      <img src="https://www.funnypica.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/funny-picture-of-ugly-indian.jpg"/>
      <img src="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/03434/guinness-eyeballs_3434500k.jpg"/>
      <img src="https://www.allindiaroundup.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/mr-bean-pics-as-a-baby-whatsapp-dp-1024x768.jpg"/>
      <img src="http://www.likecool.com/Gear/Pic/10%20Vintage%20Pics%20Of%20Carrie%20Fisher%20Promoting%20%20Return%20Of%20The%20Jedi%20%20In/10-Vintage-Pics-Of-Carrie-Fisher-Promoting--Return-Of-The-Jedi--In-2.jpg"/>
      <img src="http://8.mshcdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/steve-jobs-finger.jpg"/>
      <img src="https://www.funnypica.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/funny-picture-of-ugly-indian.jpg"/>
    </div>
```

Comment: It's almost what I need, but the tricky part is that in this case, what is scrolling is de "body" itself, but what I would like to scroll is the "grid" div, i also tried wrapping the "grid" div but it didn't work iether

Comment: Then you need to fix(header/footer if applicable to be position fixed and add overflow-y:scroll to your grid. This should to the trick you want)